# if-else sentence in one-line-python

Tags: python

I have some code:

```
a_part = [2001, 12000]
b_part = [1001, 2000]
c_part = [11, 1000]
d_part = [1, 10]
data = range(1, 12000)
labels = [a_part, b_part, c_part, d_part]
sizes = []

# ---

for part in labels:
    sum = 0
    for each in data:
        sum += each if each >= part[0] and each <= part[1] else 0
        # error
        # sum += each if each >= part[0] and each <= part[1] 
    sizes.append(sum)
print(sizes)
```

And I rewrote this to be more Pythonic:

```
sizes = [sum(x for x in data if low<=x<=high) for low,high in labels]
# error
# sizes = [sum(x for x in data if low<=x<=high else 0) for low else 0,high in labels]
print(sizes)
```

I found that in the first snippet I can't leave out `else 0` while the second example can't contain `else 0`.

What is the difference `else 0` makes between these examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two very different things here.

In the first you have an expression, and are using a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to produce the value; that requires an `else` because an expression always needs to produce *something*.

For example, if you wrote:

```
sum += each if each >= part[0] and each <= part[1]  # removing "else 0"
```

then what would be added to the sum if the test was false?

In the second you have a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), and the `if` is part of the possible parts (called [`comp_if` in the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)), next to (nested) `for` loops. Like an `if ...:` statement, it filters what elements in the sequence are used, and that doesn't need to produce a value in the *false* case; you would not be filtering otherwise.

To bring that back to your example:

```
sum(x for x in data if low<=x<=high)
```

when the `if` test is false, that `x` is just omitted from the loop and not summed. You'd do the same thing in the first example with:

```
if each >= part[0] and each <= part[1]:
    # only add to `sum` if true
    sum += each
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the same syntax at all.  The first one is a ternary operator (like (a ? b : c) in C). It wouldn't make any sense not to have the else clause here. The second one is a list comprehension and the purpose of the if clause is to filter the elements of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

```
x if y else z
```

This is an inline-if expression which returns a value. It must always return a value, it cannot not return a value, hence it must contain an `else` clause.

```
[x for x in y if z]
```

This is a list comprehension. The `if` here acts as a filter for the loop. It's equivalent to `for x in y: if z: ...`.

To have an `else` in there, you put the inline-if expression in place of `x`:

```
[x if y else z for foo in bar]
```